# Show loading option in angularjs while fetching content using $http

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a directive so we have a reusable way to show an option labeled 'Loading...' in a select tag. The problematic comes because I'd like to be notified just about a specified connection (as shown in the fiddle) and because I'd like the directive to know nothing about the model ($scope).

The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/5UhBn/8/ with all the code, but I'll show you what I'm trying at the moment. The following handler is called at the start of a connection:

```
var startRequestHandler = function() {
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(obj);
    selectCtrl.addOption(msg);
    /**
     * Above I'd want Angular adding the element to the combo.
     **/
    console.log('Started endRequestHandler');
};
```

The next handler is called when the connection is done and resets the value:

```
var endRequestHandler = function() {
    selectCtrl.removeOption(msg);
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(null);
    /**
    * Above I'd want Angular removing the element from the combo.
    **/
    console.log('Ended endRequestHandler');
};
```

Thank you!